# redirecting output of shell to a file with ampersand returns some additional commands in output

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have a simple shell script which contains echo statement as below.

```
-bash-3.2$ vi dummy.sh
echo "hi"
```

If i simply execute that file it writes `"hi"` as output to a file called `"text"` as below

```
-bash-3.2$ ksh dummy.sh > text
-bash-3.2$ cat text
hi
-bash-3.2$
```

Now , If I execute the same script with `&`  at the end, its writing `hi` output with other command text as below.

```
-bash-3.2$ ksh dummy.sh > text &
[1] 11208
-bash-3.2$ cat text
hi
[1]+  Done                    ksh dummy.sh > text
-bash-3.2$
```

I dont want to print `[1]+  Done                    ksh dummy.sh > text` line in the output file called `text` with `&` mode.
Could any one please tell me how to achieve this as i need to execute 100s of scripts in backend mode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following line is not appended to the file.

```
[1]+  Done                    ksh dummy.sh > text
```

It is printed by shell to let you know the background process is terminated.

Try `cat text` again, then you will notice that there's no line with `[1] ....`.

Comment: Alternatively simply hit `enter` before running `cat`. Or use `set -b` to turn on immediate notification and just wait a moment before running `cat`.

Comment: @EtanReisner : Do i have to append set -b ?

Comment: @logan, run `set -b` before run background jobs. The shell will still print the `[1] ...`, but it will print it as soon as the background job finish.